# What format is this colour value? 0x000066FF

Tags: colors, hex

Can anyone tell me what format this colour value is in: 0x000066FF.

I believe its a 16 bit hex with an Alpha Channel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right - looks like an [ARGB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_space) value.

> ARGB values are typically expressed using 8 hexadecimal digits, with each pair of the hexadecimal digits representing the sample values of the Alpha, Red, Green and Blue channel, respectively. For example, 0x80FFFF00 represents 50.2% opaque (non-premultiplied) yellow. The "0x" prefix is used to identify a number as hexadecimal in C notation. 0x80 represents a 50.2% alpha value, because it is 50.2% of 0xFF (in decimal 128 is 50.2% of 255), the first 0xFF represents the maximum value a red sample can have; the second 0xFF is like the previous but for green; 0x00 represents the minimum value a blue sample can have (effectively – no blue). Consequently red + green yields yellow.